# Missing overload for Color.FromArgb(int32, color) method

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create new color by taking existing one and giving it new alpha value. Documentation says this overload exists, but when I try to use it, IDE says there's no such overload and code won't build. What am I missing?

Comment: That is a Winforms method, let the IntelliSense popup help you find the correct one.

Comment: How do you know it is winforms method? It is not mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `System.Drawing` is a WinForms namespace. It is a GDI+ wrapper. You *can* use it in a WPF application, but you shouldn't. The reason this isn't working is probably because you haven't added the correct reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
var c = Colors.Aqua;
var newColor =  new Color {A = 50, R=c.R, G=c.G,B=c.B};
```

I understand you want an overload, but as far as I'm aware one does not exist and you need to do the above.

Comment: Nothing's wrong, but the overload I wanted to use was a simpler. Documentation was a bit misleading though, so I ended up asking here.

Comment: What if I'd want to use a variable instead of int value? Should I cast it or there's another way?

Comment: I can't say without more information about that the variable is. But at the end of day it would need to be an int. So if the var is a json or xml etc, it will eventually need to be cast to an int to feed into the Color class.